# OpenCV template matching or feature detection to correctly categorize types of faxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, feature-detection, template-matching

Sorry, this is my first time posting a question.

I need a process to identify images within other images to be able to categorize images (ex. sorting faxes based on a company symbol).

I have tried openCV template matching but I doesn't seem to be that accurate and if I try to use it by looping through multiple images I cant seem to find a threshold of accuracy that would tell me there is a correct match.

I have also tried openCV feature matching with ORB but it seems that my images might not be complex enough so the features get matched all over the page.

For template matching I follow the basic code from the documentation:

```
# load the image image, convert it to grayscale, and detect edges
template = cv2.imread('PATH TO TEMPLATE IMAGE')
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("Template", template)

match_list = []
# loop over the images to find the template in
for imagePath in glob.glob('PATH TO DIRECTORY OF IMAGES'):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
    # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None

    # loop over the scales of the image
    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
        # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
        # of the ratio of the resizing
        resized = imutils.resize(gray, width = int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
        # from the loop
        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break

        # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
        # matching to find the template in the image
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    match_list.append((maxVal, imagePath))

print(match_list)
```

My questions are:

1. Am I on the right track as far as which openCV process to use?
2. If I use template matching how can I use it to categorize images based on and exact or close to exact match?

Thanks!

Part 2: This is the template matching code Ive gone with.

```
template = cv2.imread('/Users/ME/Documents/so_temp.tiff',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

match_values = []
for imagePath in glob.glob('/Users/ME/Documents' + "/*.tiff"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
    # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    img2 = img.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    methods = ['cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED']

    for meth in methods:
        img = img2.copy()
        method = eval(meth)

        # Apply template Matching
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template,method)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        match_values.append((min_val, max_val, imagePath))
        print (min_val, max_val, imagePath)

        # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
        if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
            top_left = min_loc
        else:
            top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

        cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

        plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
        plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
        plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.suptitle(meth)

        plt.show()
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hILCP.png)

But keep in mind that Im doing this over many faxes and the template matching returns too many false positives, so I need suggestions on what I can do to, either through training or image processing, to return the one correct fax that matches the template.

There is also the problem of identifying the fax if the fax image is upside down, which can be done through feature detection, but I cant seem to get working through template matching.

I hope I made this clearer, thank you.

Comment: You'll need to give some examples of a logo and pages that template matching fails on. Template matching or feature matching is definitely sufficient for this purpose, so let's see how you could better the result by looking at the cases where it works and where it doesn't.

Comment: Yikes, I was contemplating even asking this question because the forms in question have patient information (so they cannot be posted) and I know its difficult to explain what exactly is happening. If there are any suggestions for how to improve the accuracy of either template matching or feature detection that would be helpful. Basically they are all black and white forms with a lot of text and a small to medium sized company logo in the corner.

Comment: That's fine. But could you recreate such cases? Or at least expand on the issues? What exactly is making a threshold not good enough? Is the preprocessing bad so you've got not good binarization? Or is the template the wrong size? If feature matching is giving bad matches, please be more specific here; how many features are on an example template? What about the best 4 matches? Both of those methods (template matching or feature matching) are the standard for doing this task, but there is no way for an answerer to suggest how to better your pipeline w/o more info.

Comment: Ok, I added a part 2 that I hope explains things better, Im focusing mostly on template matching for now because Ive made more headway with it. I don't think the template is the wrong size, what size should it be to make it better?

Comment: Template matching is not scale invariant, it will only match if the size is the same. Are you guaranteed that your templates will be the same size? For e.g. if all your scans are the same size and the template is the same size as how it will appear on the image, you are fine. But if your scans are different size, or if the logo may appear at different scales then you need to loop through multiple scales of your template. See [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/).

Comment: Template matching is also harder to threshold on binary images typically, because you have a lot of white in your template and there's a lot of white in the image in general, so the scores will be high everywhere. You might consider adding a mask to only check the black area in the template and ignore the white.

Comment: I did the scaling but the results seemed to be worse, where they all returned the same score. I attempted to write a mask into my code but I cant seem to get anything working. Do you have any good examples?

Comment: I should have mentioned it earlier, but template matching with a mask only works for two of the available template matching methods: `TM_SQDIFF` and `TM_CCORR_NORMED`. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) (Python documentation is not up yet for the `mask` parameter, but you can pass it in as the last argument).